# How do I get other Android emulator models for use in the VS 2019 debugger?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a simple Xamarin Forms app.  In the Visual Studio 20190 debugger, I am given a choice between using an emulator for the "Galaxy Nexus Pie 9.0 - API 28 (Android 9.0 - API 28)", or to create an emulator from scratch using a large page of parameters to choose from, none of which I understand.  Since I own a Galaxy Note 10, I'd like to use that for my emulator.  How do I add an emulator for that phone?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds

Comment: You could manage Virtual Devices with the Android Device Manager. Please check the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows